# Relative path as source for droplink or droplist?

Tags: templates, sitecore

I'm trying to specify a relative path for the source of a droplink/dropsource.

Specifically, I have a folder structure where I have an Authors folder under a certain branch.  On the same level of that Authors folder, there can be items or folders with items that will have a droplist that could point to that Authors folder for it's source.  The issue though is that this is going to be repeated for multiple clients, so I don't want to have to manually specify the source directory in each case but rather just have a relative source that says basically find the closest Authors folder to me (sibling, aunt/uncle, great aunt/uncle, etc.).  Any way to do this?  Do I need to use Sitecore query syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible with a query.

In the Source field of your droplink Template field set something like:

```
query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='yoursitesite']/home/*
```

or

```
query:../*
```

Depend on your exact structure, or template names.

See:

For SXA, see [use-a-query-to-determine-the-data-source-context](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/use-a-query-to-determine-the-data-source-context.html)

More explanation [sitecore-field-source-as-xpath-query-or-fastquery-cheat-sheet/](https://horizontalintegration.blog/2015/05/17/sitecore-field-source-as-xpath-query-or-fastquery-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: Thanks, query:ancestor::*/Authors/* seems to be the thing that works for me.